# Error message in software center - not in lp-ppa-pasgui

Tags: apt

I tried to publish a review for Homebank and got the error message "package homebank  not in lp-ppa-pasgui precise for precise". What is it trying to tell me? I haven't removed any software sources since Homebank was installed and pasgui is in the list as (http://)"ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/pps/ubuntu precise main". I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with all updates current.

Answer (score 1):

> What is it trying to tell me?

That it doesn't exist anymore.

> pasgui is in the list as http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/pps/ubuntu precise main

There is the problem, it isn't `pps` but `ppa`. If you click the same link you will be found with a Not Found (404) error. Remove the line from your sources.list then run this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Now it should work fine.